# Entity framework custom migrations

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

When adding migration can you make the generator add some code to Up() method?

Like a piece of code that would run itself before every migration.

I know you can write it yourself and everything, but can it be done automatically?

Comment: You can run migrations from inside your code (as opposed to the package manager console). This would allow you to run code before the migrations. https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: @SteveGreene I want to inject code directly into migration, so at a later date I can see when my code made changes to db. Also your link only shows how to run migrations from code, not create them (not that it would help).

Comment: Well, it runs the migrations you create from the console. If you explain a little more about what you are after it might help. Below you mention you want to inject some SQL in every migration, but not manually. The problem is migrations trigger from model changes. You might be able to add to the migration Seed() which runs after every migration.

Comment: @SteveGreene that's the thing, I want to inject code that will run before every migration and I don't want to do it manually. Fro all I've gathered so far it seems like you can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MigrationOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.migrationoperation(v=vs.113).aspx), that allows to declare a database agnostic action to execute during migrations and implement it for a specific database vendor.

Take a look to [this](https://romiller.com/2013/02/27/ef6-writing-your-own-code-first-migration-operations/) post to see how it works

Comment: But I have to manually write the code in Up() method. Can it be done automatically?

Comment: I want every Up() to contain a call to a method that does some work and then generates SQL (like in the link). The link you provided is usefull and I will use it, I just don't want to write the call to the method manually.

Comment: I don't think you can change how VS generates those classes. I would define an abstract class _CustomDBMigration_ that inherits from _DBMigration_ and call your custom code in the _Up_ method. You will then generate automatically the standard migration classes  with Visual Studio and manually change the inheritance from _DBMigration_ to  _CustomDBMigration_

Comment: I don't want to do anything manually. I was wandering if there is a way to fully automate process.

Comment: Understood. I don't think it's possibile but let's if someone could help you